Does file_picker on flutter not request permission from the user?
I'm using flutter + file_picker 8.0.7. Both iOS and Android allow me to access document files on my device without having to ask users for permission. Is this normal?
It is part of AndroidMenifest.xml.
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- External Storage Read Permission (Access Storage Under Android 13)-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- External storage write permission (android 9 and below) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- (Common with Android 11 and later) If you need Manage External Storage rights in addition to media (you need to fill out the Declaration of Rights form when submitting apps to the Google Play Store -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>-->
    <!-- (Android 13 and later) Media access segmentation, IMAGES/VIDEO all show only one permission request on request -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <!-- (Android 14 and later) Photo/Video partial access -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" />


When I asked Gemini (file_picker and permission)
ios : It is said that you do not need to receive additional permissions because you use the UIDocument Interaction controller.
android : Android 10 and below request permission to read_external_storage, and Android 11 and above do not need to request permission separately.
I can't trust it. Somewhere, Android said that media files should give READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and so on, and use SAF to access other files. But I don't even know if file_picker is using SAF (I don't fully know SAF itself yet) This seems to conflict with Gemini's opinion.
As Gemini said, do I need permission to access media files (photos, videos, etc.) and I don't need to get permission from users when I access other document files??
I wrote androidMenifest.xml as above, and I just used file_picker. Other than that, I didn't do anything about permission. The test instrument is android 14.

file_picker does use SAF internally for document picking, which is why you can access documents without explicit permissions. SAF shows a system picker UI where users implicitly grant permission by selecting files. But for Media files explicit permissions are needed and it must be requested at runtime.

You don't need any permission to use file picker. When file picker is used and files are selected by the user, you get access to those files only, that too, once. There's no permanent access to files or folders, that's why no permission is required

"On devices that run Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher, your app
can interact with a documents provider, including external storage
volumes and cloud-based storage, using the Storage Access Framework.
This framework allows users to interact with a system picker to choose
a documents provider and select specific documents and other files for
your app to create, open, or modify.
Because the user is involved in selecting the files or directories
that your app can access, this mechanism doesn't require any system
permissions, and user control and privacy is enhanced. Additionally,
these files, which are stored outside of an app-specific directory and
outside of the media store, remain on the device after your app is
uninstalled.
Using the framework involves the following steps:
An app invokes an intent that contains a storage-related action. This
action corresponds to a specific use case that the framework makes
available. The user sees a system picker, allowing them to browse a
documents provider and choose a location or document where the
storage-related action takes place. The app gains read and write
access to a URI that represents the user's chosen location or
document. Using this URI, the app can perform operations on the chosen
location."

Access documents and other files from shared storage 
